# Wordpress Remove Lazy Load from Main Product Image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Need to prevent the main image on the product page from lazy loading.

The main product image is loaded in 'woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php'

It uses: wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size, $icon, $attr ); to get the image.

Inside the function above, there is:

```
// Add `loading` attribute.
    if ( wp_lazy_loading_enabled( 'img', 'wp_get_attachment_image' ) ) {
        $default_attr['loading'] = wp_get_loading_attr_default( 'wp_get_attachment_image' );
    }

    $attr = wp_parse_args( $attr, $default_attr );

    // If the default value of `lazy` for the `loading` attribute is overridden
    // to omit the attribute for this image, ensure it is not included.
    if ( array_key_exists( 'loading', $attr ) && ! $attr['loading'] ) {
        unset( $attr['loading'] );
    }
```

So clearly it's possible to not lazy load it, but I just don't fully understand how I can do this?

Answer (score 3):

A way you can handle this is by creating a conditional that checks if you are currently on a single product page using the `is_product()` conditional provided by WooCommerce found [here](https://woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-7).

Also, instead of unsetting `attr['loading']`, you can set it to `eager` to ensure that the browser does not automatically set it as something else.

Your final code could look something like this:

```
function remove_lazy_load($attr, $attachment, $size){

   if ( is_product() ) {
      $attr['loading'] = 'eager';
   }

   return $attr;

}
add_filter("wp_get_attachment_image_attributes", 'remove_lazy_load', 10, 3);
```

edit:
I ended up actually having to implement this myself and this is the solution I came up with

```
function remove_lazy_load($attr, $attachment, $size){
  // check if we're on the single product page
  if(is_product()){

    // main product image has the class wp-post-image so we'll check the attributes of the image if it contains the class
    if(strpos($attr['class'], 'wp-post-image') !== false){

      // you can unset but I prefer to explicitly set it
      $attr['loading'] = "eager";
    }
  }

  return $attr;

}
add_filter("wp_get_attachment_image_attributes", 'remove_lazy_load', 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip. If the goal is to get more immediate rendering of the primary product photo, I found also adding this line helped: $attr['decoding'] = "sync";

Answer (score 0):

one way you might be able to do this is to use the `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` filter like below:

```
<?php

add_filter("wp_get_attachment_image_attributes", function($attr, $attachment, $size) {
    $first_image_post_id = 'ID of the image you want to remove the lazy attr';
    
    if ( $attachment->ID === $first_image_post_id ) {
        unset( $attr['loading'] );
    }

    return $attr;
}, 10, 3);
```

More info on the WP docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_attachment_image_attributes/

Comment: How can I pass in the ID of the main into this filter?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'remove_img_attr', 10, 2 );
function remove_img_attr( $attr, $attachment ) {
    unset( $attr['id'] );
    return $attr;
}
```

Comment: This shows me how to unset an attribute from the images but I need to unset it for the first image